# Collapse accordian branch before expanding another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I have been working on someone else's webpage that has an accordian.

Their relevant JQuery code portion is:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".accordion").on("click", ".trigger", function (n) {
                var t, i;
                n.preventDefault();
                t = $(this).parent();
                t.hasClass("open") ? t.find(".content").animate({ height: 0 }, 500, function () { t.removeClass("open") }) :
                    ($(".open .content").animate({ height: 0 }, 500, function () { $(this).parents(".open").removeClass("open") }),
                        i = t.find(".inner").height(), t.find(".content").animate({ height: i }, 500, function () { t.addClass("open"); $(this).height("auto") }))
            })
        });
```

I know I haven't uploaded the HTML (there's quite a lot) but I was hoping someone might be able to tell me how the jQuery code could be amended so any open branch collapses before the clicked one opens (only one is currently ever allowed to be open at a time).

As present, because the branches contain a whole lot of images and text, the new branch isn't opening at the top of its content but rather for example half way down. I can see that if I manually collapse the previously opened branch first then open the new one, it all appears fine. So I thought if the code could be changed to close the old branch first it would have the scroll position of the new branch content correctly at located its top.

UPDATE 1:
Here's an HTML extract from the first branch which is opened on page load and contains a video.

```
<ul class="accordion">
                <!-- Question 1 Start -->
                <li class="open">
                    <div class="trigger dvQuestionTitleTable dvQuestion1 dvQuestionAlignment">
                        <div id="dvIDQuestion1" class="dvQuestionTitleRow" onclick="fJTogglePlusMinus(1)">
                            <div class="theme-agent-heading-sub dvQuestionTitleTextCell">
                                Video
                            </div>
                            <div id="dvIDPlusMinusImage1" class="dvQuestionTitleImageCell">
                                <img id="Image1" src="../../common/images/icons/icon-help-minus.svg" class="imgMinus">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dvTopHorizontalLineArea">
                        <div class="dvHRLine">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="theme-help-answer">
                                <div class="dvVideoContainer1">
                                    <video loop="" playsinline="" id="Video100" width="100%" controls="" poster="/pages/agent/resources/video/images/video-100-poster-image.jpg">
                                        <source src="video/video-100.webm" type="video/webm">
                                        <source src="video/video-100.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                                    </video>
                                </div>
```

Comment: can you consider removing the animation on close?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Thanks for the thought but we'd still need that so it didn't jump around, especially if they manually closed a branch.

Comment: anyway you can share the HTML structure?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Please see Update 1 above.

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph No.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198462/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-user1946932).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test - added: .delay(500)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".accordion").on("click", ".trigger", function(n) {
        var t, i;
        n.preventDefault();
        t = $(this).parent();
        t.hasClass("open") ? t.find(".content").animate({
                height: 0
            }, 500, function() {
                t.removeClass("open")
            }) :
            ($(".open .content").animate({
                    height: 0
                }, 500, function() {
                    $(this).parents(".open").removeClass("open")
                }),
                i = t.find(".inner").height(), t.find(".content").delay(500).animate({
                    height: i
                }, 500, function() {
                    t.addClass("open");
                    $(this).height("auto")
                }))
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `slideUp` and `slideDown`. Also, may not need to check `t.hasClass("open")` as your intention is to close all accordions first and open the selected one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".accordion").on("click", ".trigger", function(n) {
    var t, i;
    n.preventDefault();
    t = $(this).parent();

    if (t.hasClass("open")) { // check if the el is opened; need to close the el
      t.find(".content").slideUp('fast', function() {
        $(".accordion").removeClass("open")
      });
      return;
    } else {
      $(".open .content").slideUp('fast', function() {
        $(".accordion").removeClass("open")
      });
    }
    t.find(".content").slideDown('fast', function() {
      t.addClass("open");
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I can try tomorrow at the office and let you know.

Comment: Thanks but 1) The old functionality allowed a user to click a second time on the heading they just expanded to have it collapse again. I tried your code but that functionality was lost. 2) When a new branch heading was clicked using the code you provided, the branch image/text content was scrolled to the midway or end point so the user still would have to manually scroll up to the top of it to see the beginning of its content.

Comment: have updated the code to fix `#1`, can you explain a bit more on `#2` ?

Comment: If a branch contains three tall skinny images each underneath each other, the first thing the user sees after expanding is the bottom half of the third image. That’s why we wanted to wait until the open branch collapse animation was completed before opening a new one. Manually done that works fine. Also BTW, your expansion code animation wasn’t smooth like the original.

Comment: its really hard this way, lets see if you can get a working fiddle. There is not point in guessing and fixing, sorry :)